# PostgreSQL: Using CTE with IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, dbeaver

Learning CTE right now, the following query is super basic and it doesn't really have any useful value but I don't understand why it doesn't work

```
with cte_actors as (
    select first_name from actor where first_name like 'P%' or first_name like 'E%'
)

select
    first_name
from
    actor
where
    first_name in (cte_actors)
```

The error I'm getting is "ERROR: column "cte_actors" does not exist"

Currently using postgres 14 and DBeaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to SELECT from the CTE:

```
with cte_actors as (
    select first_name 
    from actor 
    where first_name like 'P%' or first_name like 'E%'
)
select first_name
from actor
where first_name in (select first_name from cte_actors)
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'll need to do more research to understand why it needs to be done like that though, but thank you for your help